# Computer's wireless connection stops working until reboot

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, internet, reboot

One of my coworkers asked me to help her with the internet connection on her computer. She is running Vista on a pretty old laptop, but it's still functional.

The problem is the following:
Every once in a while, her internet connection will disappear, and will not come back until she reboots the computer.
I tried troubleshooting, disabling and enabling her connection, but this just made all of the wireless networks in range disappear.

Since I did not have long with her computer, I did not try releasing and renewing ipconfig, though next time it happens I'll tell her to let me know.

I was wondering if anyone had had this happen before, and had fixed it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uninstall Vista, install 7.  (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: Though it doesn't solve my problem easily, I agree 100%.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by a driver/firmware bug or failing hardware.  Did you make sure she was running the latest driver for her wireless card?

Brand new USB wireless adaptors can be bought for well under $20, meaning you can probably get used ones for next to nothing.  At those prices, it might not hurt to try a different crappy wireless adaptor and hope it happens to be less crappy than the one she's already got.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem for years but finally, I fixed it and I wanted to share with you all guys, I bet this method %100 would work unlike the other methods, all you have to do is just uninstall your antivirus or just stop your antivirus from changing internet settings.